# Android async image load

Tags: android

So I have an activity with an ImageView. My goal is to have the activity start and asynchronously fetch the image I need in there. While the image is being fetched, I'd like to display some sort of spinning loading symbol in place of the image. I've tried using AsyncTask as a separate class, but ran into issues relating to modifying the views of another activity. I tried an anonymous Runnable class inside the activity, but it doesn't seem to be yielding the effects I expect. Can anyone advise?

SOLVED: Simply needed a handler in the activity

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
          public void  handleMessage(Message msg) {
              ImageView qrCode =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qr); 
              qrCode.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)msg.obj);
          }
     };


    new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
                bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
                int retry = 0;
                Bitmap bm = null;
                while(retry < 50 && bm == null){
                    bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
                    if(bm == null){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    retry++;
                }
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = bm;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                return;
            } 


    }).start();
    `
```

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place a progress dialog inside of the view with the imageview.
set the imageview ImageView.visibility(View.INVISIBLE);

In your preExecute() in your AsyncTask

Show the spinning dialog, and then do the fetching in the doInBackground() of the AsyncTask

In onPostExecute() show your imageview by changing the visibility and dismiss the dialog or sets its visibility to View.GONE

Comment: Wouldn't modifying the ImageView (setting what the bitmap is) belonging to the activity in a separate AsyncTask class bring up the error I described?

Answer (score 0):

Android's developer guide for threading should help you out.  It has AsyncTask examples that pretty much do exactly what you're asking for:
[Android Threading Guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

If you don't implement the publishProgress() method, and only implement doInBackground to get the data, and onPostExecute to update the UI, then it should by default give you the spinning icon to indicate that it's loading.  Keep in mind that onPostExecute runs on the main UI thread so you can't make any network calls from there

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar and did according to this tutorial:

http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/lazy-loading-images-in-a-listview